# Applescript gives error permission denied when trying to open png file through python script

Tags: python, applescript

Hello so I made a script that takes a screenshot then reads text from the screenshot all in python and it works fine. However I am trying to get the script to run from Applescript and I am getting an error.

I have tried to use "shell" however that is not working.

This is part of the python script:

```py
im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(100,200,1250,700))
im.save('duolingo.png')

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/4.0.0_1/bin/tesseract'

x = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('duolingo.png'))
```

And the Applescript:

```py
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/user/Documents/duolingobot.py $@"
```

This is my error I am getting:

```
error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \"/Users/user/Documents/duolingobot.py\", line 11, in <module>
    im.save('duolingo.png')
  File \"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py\", line 2004, in save
    fp = builtins.open(filename, \"w+b\")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'duolingo.png'" number 1
```

Comment: Try saving it to somewhere you know you can write to like `/tmp/duolingo.png` as you can't be sure which directory your script is running in.

Comment: You could try `do shell script "/usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/user/Documents/duolingobot.py $@" with administrator privileges`